# How to get the Paralysis spell?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do I get paralysis? I am a 100 Alteration. I've been searching for it,I have checked the Winterhold College and every single city that has a mage that sells spells.Is it a glitch?I've reloaded and even made a new character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paralysis is sold by [Tolfdir](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Tolfdir) at the College of Winterhold when you reach 75 skill in Alteration. if you have just joined the college Tolfdir is likely at Saarthal waiting for you, which could be the reason you failed to find him at the College.

Comment: I forgot to do the Saarthal quest.Thank you very much!

Comment: You can actually gain the ability to buy the spell with a skill level of only 65.